# Write file limit to 64kb

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, ubuntu-14.04

Hi I'm using codeigniter with sql-server in ubuntu 14.2 and window server for database.

I'm storing my file in database using hex data.

I want to write it back to file but when the file is bigger then 64kb, the file will be the size of 64kb. If the file size is less than 64kb the file write normally.

I have already change php.ini and `ini_get` return result as

```
["max_upload"]=> int(2048) ["max_post"]=> int(2048) ["memory_limit"]=> int(2048)
```

I have manage to resolve this on the previous server. And it works. I forget what is the setting. This previous server now is corrupt due to my mistake changing the permission on /etc folder accidentally.

Comment: I don't know enough about SQL Sever, but do you sure about the specifications of the field type where you store the data?

Comment: generally - don't store files in the db, use the file system, store the file name\location in the db. In this case what field type are you storing it in ?

Comment: I'm sure about the field type. If the file size is below 64kb then it will write without a problem. Like i mention, this script is running before. After i accidentally rewrite permission on the server and setup a new one. I could't get the setting i set before.

Comment: I have check my data length in database and the result of query. Apparently the result got only 64kb of length while in database the data is more than that. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i got it.

change the

```
; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
mssql.textlimit = 2147483647

; Valid range 0 - 2147483647.  Default = 4096.
mssql.textsize = 2147483647
```

in php.ini.

The default only allow 64kb data. So need to change it for bigger data.

Tq for all the help.